# Suitable clustering for the project

Tags: machine-learning

I am working on a project where I need to apply machine learning: My questions are:

1) Whether I am correct that nested clustering will suit to this problem statement and the algorithm which I have thought about is correct to implement in this scenario

2) If not then suggest me which algorithm should be implemented

Problem statement: Suppose we have a form in which user can enter issues that could occur in a company. So, without mentioning the department name (just from the problem/issue), machine has to cluster the issues related to each department/category like finance, hr dept etc.

Now in each department/category, there can be many issues that can point to the same issue like:

In HR department many people have reported this issue:

-Temp is too high today
-It's 47 C, but I want 27 C
-It's too warm inside HR dept etc.

So, I am thinking that hierarchical clustering should be implemented, firstly for having clusters of issues related to each department and then again within each department clusters should be there for similar issues.

Also, initial category/department are not fix, so classification with clustering cannot be applied.

Hope my question is pretty clear. Any leads as whether I am doing right or need to think again about this problem's solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On the business side, it's far from clear that such a strategy would work. If the fax isn't widely used, you may have a cluster of fax questions which you don't detect because only a few people per department use the fax.

Practically speaking, you would need high-grade Natural Language Processing first. Is 47 C a room number or a temperature? "It's an oven here" would fit the category, too. Californians would also understand "It feels like Death Valley here" but not everyone would realize that's a complaint about the heat, let alone a machine. Another such example: "The air is broken" - in a complaint form, that would be the air conditioning.

In general, the biggest issue I see is that the "department" class is woefully underspecified. Are you complaining about problems that exist physically in a department (it's hot in HR) or are you mentioning the department that must come fix it (Send someone from facilities, it's too hot here)

Comment: 47 C represents temperature here (did not know how to represent degree). Yes, I want to have a form that could be used by staff members to complaint about issues so that mail can be send to concerned person to look after that issue/problem. Now, by overthinking this problem, what I got is I need two layers while doing clustering means at one layer all the departments/area/domain (like HR, Finance, Reception, Entrance... etc) are there and again at next level sub clusters in each clusters are there. Hope you can visualize this what I wanna say....

Comment: @priya: It's not about what _YOU_ know about 47C. It's what the parser knows. The complaint may very well miss the degree sign, too. It will have to know that 401K isn't 401 Kelvin (rather hot temperature) but a  pension thing and therefore has to be assigned to HR.

Comment: Thanx, so can you suggest how to proceed as while googling, I could only find hierarchical clustering but that does not satisfies what I wanna do...